# Why my localhost of phpMyAdmin is showing this error?

Tags: laravel, wordpress, phpmyadmin, localhost, ampps

[image]
Error
MySQL said: Documentation

> Cannot connect: invalid settings.  mysqli_real_connect(): The server
> requested authentication method unknown to the client
> [caching_sha2_password]  mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2054): The
> server requested authentication method unknown to the client
> phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server
> rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and
> password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to
> the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server.

Comment: Try to organize your question. Also, first try to fix it using what is mentioned in the error."You should check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server."

Answer (score 0):

Check php version or reinstall xampp

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).